# whenever using database library,error message is displayed

Tags: php, codeigniter

whenever loading this

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

error is shown
**Unable to load the requested class: database**
without the above mentioned code,the following error is shown.

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: LoginPage::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 52
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Test_LR\application\models\Login_model.php on line 11

Comment: Unable to load the requested class: database<--- encountered this error

Comment: how to solve it then?

Comment: sorry. can you be more specific??i didnt get which folder is to be checked.can you specify the procedure as well. thanks.

Comment: You are on localhost so it doesn't look like permission issue.. try a fresh download and install of ci :)

Comment: i am not on localhost.currentently connected to development server.

Comment: i could not find this window. from xampp,how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIle permission From Filezilla...

`Connect your FTP client to your web server.  In FileZilla, right-click the "system" folder on your web server and choose File Permissions to open the file attributes. Type the correct number in the Numeric Value text field`

[image]

Comment: i could not find this window.

Answer (score 0):

This means CodeIgniter has a library `database`.

You can include libraries in two ways:

1) In `application/config/autoload.php`

Code:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); // Include other libraries here like `session`.
```

2) Run time by using `$this->load->library('database');` if not included with first method.

Without it, it will show fatal error.

Comment: yes.i have tried that code .but yielded another error -->**Unable to load the requested class: database**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use:

```
$this->load->database();  
Instead of $this->load->library('database');
```

Or double check if your database file available on system

Sample example Usersmodel.php

```
class usersmodel extends CI_Model
 { 
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function examplefunction()
    {
    }
}
```